# Display the variation description value in WooCommerce admin edit order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I am wondering if it's possible to display the product variation description field in the admin edit order page like:

[image: (http://prntscr.com/oyq03o).]

I have been able to add it in cart page using a WooCommerce hook, but can't get the same for order items in admin edit order page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can have many order items in an order, is better to display it directly in order items, instead below the order "General" data section.

The following will display the **variation description** on admin edit order page on order items:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta', 'add_admin_order_item_variation_description', 10, 2 );
function add_admin_order_item_variation_description( $item_id, $item ) {
    // Targeting line items type only
    if( $item->get_type() !== 'line_item' ) return;

    $product = $item->get_product();

    if( $product->is_type('variation') && $description = $product->get_description() ) {
        // Display variation description
        echo '<div class="variation-description"><strong>' . __("Description", "woocommerce") . '</strong>: ' . $description . '</div>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

To display it below the order "General" data section, use instead *(not recommended)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'add_admin_general_order_variation_description', 20, 1 );
function add_admin_general_order_variation_description( $order ){
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        $product = $item->get_product();

        if( $product->is_type('variation') && $description = $product->get_description() ) {
            // Display variation description
            echo '<p class="form-field form-field-wide variation-description"><strong>' . __("Description", "woocommerce") . '</strong>: ' . $description . '</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.